# Which clock source is used for clocking instructions in cortex-M4

Tags: arm, stm32, cortex-m

[image]

In my Cortex-M4, I have am using a 8Mhz oscillator as HSE, which then gets multiplied to 72Mhz using PLL which then drives SYSCLK. This got me thinking, which clock is the one being used to execute instructions? In other words, if our CPI is 1 (an ideal value, of course), does that mean we would execute 8 million instructions per second or 72 million instructions per second?

I also found this [DWT](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.ddi0439b/BIIFBHIF.html) which can be used to measure clock cycles, and hence CPI. So I am guessing which ever clock that is used to execute instructions would be the same one used by DWT?

Comment: the 72mhz does clock the processor but at that speed the flash cannot keep up.  being an ST part it probably has their cache with a fancy name that actually does a really good job.  But the flash cant keep up.  The sram generally can keep up, depends on the part/implementation.  Also even though it is not that deep of a pipeline it is still pipelined, so you are not going to sustain 72MIPS except under a targeted benchmark.

Comment: The peripherals are usually not able to keep up so they often run on a slower clock (keep reading your documentation) plus it may take some/many clocks per access to a peripheral depending on that particular access at that time per that peripherals design.  So those will also take away cycles from the cpu from being able to execute instructions.

Comment: I usually just use arms systick timer if present, for cortex-ms pretty sure that is always on the cpu clock not a divisor of.  But you should have no problem running a few simple experiments and time them with systick, dwt and other timers.  Systick is easy to see if you blink an led based on it, count so many million ticks then change the state of an led, compare that to a stopwatch/timer.  A simple loop with many nops (the branch and entry point being aligned or not on a word can/will affect performance numbers so not a few instruction loop).

Comment: also understand that you need to remember that this is an st chip not an arm chip, st determined how the clocking was setup for this part not arm, so asking this as a cortex-m4 question makes no sense.  arm makes the core, the flash, the sram the clocks all the other factors in performance and feeding the core are chip and chip vendor not arm.

Comment: Ff you were to squint your eyes, make everything a bit fuzzy, stand back a long way, and assume one clock per instruction, yes it would be 72MIPS.  But thats fantasy not reality.  Think of it as your theoretical maximum.

Comment: Thanks for your insight! Can you tell me how you know that 72Mhz is the one clocking the processor? I am unsure what keywords I should be looking for in the datasheets.

Comment: Also, regarding the point you made about the ST flash, I found this snippet from the datasheet: "All STM32F302x6/8 devices feature up to 64 Kbytes of embedded Flash memory available for storing programs and data. The Flash memory access time is adjusted to the CPU clock frequency (0 wait state from 0 to 24 MHz, 1 wait state from 24 to 48 MHz and 2 wait states above)." Does that mean it would take 3 cycles to  fetch one instruction if I am using 72MHz (i.e. For every fetch instruction, I have 2 extra wait cycles). And this reduces my performance to 1/3 of the theoretical maximum already?

Comment: most likely a 32 bit bus so one clock can fetch one or two depending on if it is thumb (16 bit) or a thumb2 extention (16+16 = 32).  But yes that is what I am talking about.  If you really want to push your instructions per second you should load that code into ram and run it from ram.

Comment: basically the flash can only go 24mhz based on that information, but for thumb that means feeding up to 48Million instructions per second, theoretical max.

Comment: some of their parts have an impressive cache, that you cant turn off and they dont call it a cache.  think of it somewhere between an instruction cache and a prefetch buffer, where the logic may read ahead of the program counter in parallel while the processor is doing other stuff.  for code segments that are sequential you get a boost but may be a penalty for branches.  with a cache like approach second time through that code gets a benefit.   do some benchmarks, seriously I have beat these parts up for performance, its easy to show where they shine and dont.

Comment: but again yes you are getting the fundamental issue, flashes are getting faster but so are the cores, it is not uncommon with a pll driven clock that many parts from most of the vendors require wait states on the flash, you have to ask yourself is 72 mhz really faster than 24?  yes because other stuff is not as limited, but 72 is going to burn the most power, do you need all of that, if this part is one that the peripherals have their own speed limits 24 or 32 or 48 or whatever mhz does it make sense to go past that?

Comment: maybe you want to look at one of their cortex-m7 ones.  I cant remember of ST implemented the cache or not.  Ti I think implements caches where st leans toward their own thing.  but you have to just read the datasheet.  caches are not a performance solution, dont guarantee performance outside targeted benchmarks, benchmarks can show them helping and can show them hurting.  but for general stuff, not super performance conscious, a cache will  usually help.

Comment: or maybe you want a raspberry pi zero for your project.

Comment: Seems like the takeaway here is that there are many contributing factors to the maximum performance you can get out of a chip (e.g. flash, peripherals, caches, etc). Is the best way to just run benchmarks and see if I am actually getting performance boosts from changing the CPU clock frequency or even using a different chip?

Comment: Yes this is true for most processor based systems as the processor no longer dominates the performance. The system as a whole must be considered as well as the specific application/binary.   Your takeaway is correct.

Comment: Is there any specific recommendations you can give me for running benchmarks/profiling on an embedded system like this? For now the only thing that comes to mind is just manually inserting DWT code to measure execution time. For some context this is more of a hobby project so I don't have access to expensive hardware debuggers.

Comment: @KenLin the performacne of the core is not the most important factor when you develop the uC device. Actually I program uCs for many years and the speed was almost never the limiting factor.

Comment: I have had to change clocks as well as seen thumb2 vs pure thumb differences on these platforms.  A lot of it is just analysis, If there are timers/counters like this then sure, but understand that if you dont measure right you can mislead yourself down the wrong rabbit holes/tangents.  Only follow/believe a tangent so far before trying another path.

Comment: the simplest test to approach max performance is a loop with several/many nops ending with a sub and bne.  in asm.  wrapped by a read of whatever timer register.  prep all the addresses and loop count before the test code.  add or remove nops in front of the test (before where it is measured) to change its alignment to see how that chip fetches.  add/remove nops within the loop to also see this.  with the ST ART stuff you are running against cache and not flash other than first pass so the numbers will be off. but still reflect that mode.

Comment: repeat in sram.  then add a read from sram in the middle of the loop and a read from a peripheral register, so you can see the difference in how those perform.  likewise a write.   These can/will show sometimes significant differences in performance on these platforms, which demonstrates that you can no longer simply count instructions from some table, and you cant necessarily predict nor even benchmark the performance with a fixed list of machine code instructions as their location and how often run affects the performance.

Comment: the goal of the exercise is to realize that the timing tables are bogus.  an arm table at best would be in a sim with ideal memory, which unless you have the source code to their part, you will not achieve, and/or depending on the pipe you cant achieve even with ideal memory.  Then comes the real world vendors that purchase this ip for their products and implement the bulk of the chip or buy other ip to implement the rest of the chip and glue it all together.

Comment: I dont have an STM32F3 part off I had I have many stm32 parts, as well as other brands, and have done demonstrations like this many times.  Being able to do this yourself is a very good exercise.

Comment: get a copy of Michael Abrash's Zen of Assembly Language, can get/build a free copy on github.  While the 8086 details were obsolete when the book came out, the bigger picture is very much relevant today, I use what I learned there very off to push systems to their limits or breaking points on a regular basis.  been fortunate to work in the chip business and be able to sim and view everything, see instructions execute and hand tune code to see effects like the ones described above.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is driven from HCLK (not SYSCLK which clocks system timer and it does not have to be equal to HCLK). Thew source of HCLK is settable by the programmer.

> if our CPI is 1 (an ideal value, of course), does that mean we would
>   execute 8 million instructions per second or 72 million instructions
>   per second?

You can see how many cycles every instruction takes: http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.ddi0439b/CHDDIGAC.html

The real speed depends on many factors but mainly depends on the place where your code and data reside and the advanced uC features.

If you execute your code fro the internal TCM SRAM and place data in the SRAM (or even better on some uC in TCI and TCD SRAM)you can archive the theoretical execution efficiency as those memories work at the core clock frequency with no wait states or bus waitstates. Ideally if the uC has TC memory and both instructions and data are fetched using separate buses.

If your code resides in the FLASH memory - this memory may introduce some wait states. STM uC (ART accelerator) read the flash in larger a chunks and fetch the instructions ahead. It allows those uCs to perform almost at the max speed. The problem are branch instructions which require pipeline to be flushed and instructions fetched again.

Comment: I am using a STM32F3 series microcontoller, and it looks like there is no ART accelerator. So in this case the flash memory access speed will be the limiting factor because it introduces wait states?

Comment: it actually has the prefetch buffer and the FLASH memory bus is 64 bits so it accelerates the FLASH code execution.